# How continuous phase variation is achieved in MSK scheme?

Tags: communication, digital-communications, digital-modulation

As per my knowledge MSK(minimum shift keying) is same as FSK with the modulation index of 0.5. Now I want to understand how this 0.5 modulation index helps MSK to achieve phase continuity which was not present in FSK.

Answer (score 2):

When the difference in the two carrier frequencies generated by a logical 1 and a logical 0 is half the data rate, the modulation index is 0.5 by definition of modulation index.

When the two carrier frequencies have this relationship then there are no sudden changes in phase as can be seen with plain ordinary FSK. Here's an example of MSK: -

[image]

The two carrier frequencies produced are 1200 Hz and 1800 Hz and have a difference of 600 Hz - this difference is half the data rate (1200 baud).

It's nothing more complicated than that.

Comment: Does the difference always have to be half the data rate? For instance when using 2400 baud, the difference is 1.2 kHz, does the difference in carrier need to be that large, or can it be smaller?

Comment: @polemon this is the extreme case. If you have 100 cycles of carrier for 1 symbol, you can choose the 0 symbol to have 99 and therefore the difference in frequency shift is only 1%. But then the data rate has to be much lower compared to the carrier frequency.

Comment: The idea is to use some ISM band frequency, like 433MHz, etc. the data rate will be much lower, 9kBaud, or so. However I have trouble finding two frequencies like that, that will ensure smooth transitions. In the above example, the second '1' has its waveform inverted. How do I make sure I choose the inverted signal at any given time? If a fourth symbol, '0' would be transmitted, the waveform for the '0' would've been also inverted compared to the first transmitted '0'. How do I make sure that works?

Comment: On these occasions use a varactor controlled oscillator then no matter how hard you try, the carrier will have no discontinuities. If in doubt raise a new question and I’m sure you’ll get decent answers.